# Uploading captured video to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, performance, multithreading, network-file-transfer, raspberry-pi

My program intends to capture video streams (in mjpeg) with OpenCV and upload the captured frames into Google Cloud Storage for later processing. I am expecting to capture ~15-20 frames per second and expected to upload nearly all frames within a second.

The trick is, the script is running on Raspberry Pi 3, Model B, and together with Python, I found that it has some serious I/O limitation in terms of frames loading and uploading.

I use multiple threads to handle the loads and still find it is taking too long for uploading tasks. My current internet has a constant uplink speed of 30mbps. The received frame size is reduced to ~500KB.

I am thinking of instead of saving the frames locally, treat the loaded frames as an bytestring array and parse it accordingly in the server. But as of now, I would much prefer perhaps there is a much better solution which I am not awared of.

Below is the code I've written.

```
import os
import cv2
import sys
import time
import imutils
import datetime
from threading import Thread
from google.cloud import storage
from imutils.video import VideoStream

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    from Queue import Queue
else:
    from queue import Queue

BUCKET_NAME = "name"
RPID_FOLDER = "rpi1"
BY_DAY = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

LOCAL_STREAM_MJPEG = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg"
REMOTE_STREAM_MJPEG = "http://address:8080/stream/video.mjpeg"  

QUEUE_SIZE = 120
grabbedFrames = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
processFrames = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)


class FrameGraber(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.vs = VideoStream(src=REMOTE_STREAM_MJPEG).start()

    def run(self):
        global grabbedFrames

        while True:
            frame = self.vs.read()
            if frame is not None:
                grabbedFrames.put(frame)
                time.sleep(0.05)


class GCSUploader(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
        self.client = storage.Client()
        self.bucket = self.client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    def run(self):
        global processFrames

        while True:
            if (not processFrames.empty()):
                fileName = processFrames.get()
                try:
                    blob = self.bucket.blob("{}/{}/{}".format(RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY, fileName))
                    blob.upload_from_filename(os.path.abspath(fileName))
                    print("{} uploaded to {}/{}".format(fileName, RPID_FOLDER, BY_DAY))
                    os.remove(fileName)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)


class FrameProcessor(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.secondCount = 0
        self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second

    def run(self):
        global grabbedFrames, processFrames
        while True:

            if datetime.datetime.now().second != self.startSecond:
                self.startSecond = datetime.datetime.now().second
                self.secondCount = 0

            if (not grabbedFrames.empty()):
                frame = grabbedFrames.get()
                self.secondCount = self.secondCount + 1
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, 800)
                fileName = "{}-{}.png".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S"), self.secondCount)
                cv2.imwrite(fileName, frame)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                processFrames.put(fileName)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    uploader1 = GCSUploader()
    uploader2 = GCSUploader()
    uploader3 = GCSUploader()
    uploader4 = GCSUploader()
    uploader5 = GCSUploader()
    uploader6 = GCSUploader()
    uploader7 = GCSUploader()
    uploader8 = GCSUploader()

    frameGrabber = FrameGraber()
    frameProcessor = FrameProcessor()

    frameGrabber.start()
    frameProcessor.start()

    frameProcessor.join()
    frameGrabber.join()
    uploader1.join()
    uploader2.join()
    uploader3.join()
    uploader4.join()
    uploader5.join()
    uploader6.join()
    uploader7.join()
    uploader8.join()
```